# How would i parse the json data according to the particular property entered in JSON file using angularjs($http.get)?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have my JSON file as follows

```
{
  "colorsArray":[{
    "colorName":"red",
    "hexValue":"#f00"
  },
  {
    "colorName":"green",
    "hexValue":"#0f0"
  },
  {
    "colorName":"blue",
    "hexValue":"#00f"
  },
  {
    "colorName":"cyan",
    "hexValue":"#0ff"
  },
  {
    "colorName":"magenta",
    "hexValue":"#f0f"
  },
  {
    "colorName":"yellow",
    "hexValue":"#ff0"
  },
  {
    "colorName":"black",
    "hexValue":"#000"
  }
]}
```

And my js file for the particular as follows.....I'm reading the json file here by using `$http.get` functionality

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngTagsInput']);
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

  $scope.loadTags = function(query) {
      return $http.get('tags.json');
  };
});
```

How will I be able to get only `colorName` as parsed element when the JSON file referred  externally in `$http.get` using AngularJS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't query the json file on the fly when the request made to `json file`. One way and most efficient way is to send http call with query as parameter to  backend service method and execute and return the result from server side.

Other way is filter the result from the client side. This way all the json data will return as the response and then need to filter the relevant data from the controller '

```
$scope.loadTags = function(query) {
    return $http.get('tags.jon').then(function(response) {
        var data = response.data.map(function(obj) {
            return obj.colorName;
        })
        return data;
    })
};
```